# You must add a reference to assembly 'UnityEngine.AndroidJNIModule

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am very new at Unity and I tried to integrate Huawei Mobile Service plugin and I got this error.

The type 'AndroidJavaObject' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'UnityEngine.AndroidJNIModule

Is there anyone who encounter this problem before?
Thank you.

**Edit**
This code is belong to plugin.

```
using HuaweiMobileServices.Id;
using HuaweiMobileServices.Utils;
using System;
using UnityEngine;
namespace HmsPlugin
{
public class AccountManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    public static AccountManager GetInstance(string name = "AccountManager") => GameObject.Find(name).GetComponent<AccountManager>();

    private static HuaweiIdAuthService DefaultAuthService
    {
        get
        {
            Debug.Log("[HMS]: GET AUTH");
            var authParams = new HuaweiIdAuthParamsHelper(HuaweiIdAuthParams.DEFAULT_AUTH_REQUEST_PARAM).SetIdToken().CreateParams();
            Debug.Log("[HMS]: AUTHPARAMS AUTHSERVICE" + authParams);
            var result = HuaweiIdAuthManager.GetService(authParams);
            Debug.Log("[HMS]: RESULT AUTHSERVICE"+ result);
            return result;
        }
    }

    public AuthHuaweiId HuaweiId { get; private set; }
    public Action<AuthHuaweiId> OnSignInSuccess { get; set; }
    public Action<HMSException> OnSignInFailed { get; set; }

    private HuaweiIdAuthService authService;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Awake()
    {
        Debug.Log("[HMS]: AWAKE AUTHSERVICE");
        authService = DefaultAuthService;
    }

    public void SignIn()
    {
        Debug.Log("[HMS]: Sign in " + authService);
        authService.StartSignIn((authId) =>
        {
            HuaweiId = authId;
            OnSignInSuccess?.Invoke(authId);
        }, (error) =>
        {
            HuaweiId = null;
            OnSignInFailed?.Invoke(error);
        });
    }

    public void SignOut()
    {
        authService.SignOut();
        HuaweiId = null;
    }
}
```

}

Picture of the problem is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBB6V.png).

Comment: I believe you are not importing that Library or not referencing it to project. Can you show us your code?

Comment: I edit my question and I added picture and code. Thank you for attention.@VoidSpirit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is about my unity. I had no AndroidJNI module so I got this error. Finally I uninstall current version then install new version of Unity and problem is solved. In the new version AndroidJNI module is came automatically.